# How to set more than 3 colors in google gauge chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, gauge

I'm using Google Charts API to create a gauge chart. And I have set the options like that:

```
var options = {
   width: 350, height: 350,
   greenFrom: 0, greenTo: 50,
   yellowFrom: 51, yellowTo: 65,
   blueFrom:66, blueTo: 79,
   blueColor: "#FF4500",
   redFrom:81, redTo: 100,
   minorTicks: 5
};
```

And it is looking like :

[image: gauge chart]

but blue color is not coming in range between  66 - 79? How can I fixed this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only accepted colors are `green`, `yellow`, and `red`. Unfortunately I don't think they have included the ability to add colors beyond those three, although as you appear to know, you can change their color values.

**EDIT** Not only is it not possible, but they also do not allow colors to be given in formats that admit an alpha channel (e.g. `rgba`). So you can't even do something like

```
    var options = {
      width: 1600, height: 480,
      redFrom: 80, redTo: 100,
      redColor: "rgba(198, 0, 0, 0.67)",
      yellowFrom: 45, yellowTo: 90,
      yellowColor: "rgba(219, 190, 0, 0.67)",
      greenFrom: 25, greenTo: 45,
      minorTicks: 5
    };
```

to try to "trick" the middle color into being orange.  Too bad.  If you want more color options, looks like you need to use a different tool.

Comment: Can u do one more favour, please refer me that gauge chart which has multiple Colors zones ( more than 3 color).

Comment: I'm not sure if such a thing exists out of the box. Maybe https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/examples/ has something you can use? It seems like you could probably design your own without too much trouble if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit in Google Gauge (3 colours) as I've read in asociated forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/Z6ghp0rsjM0/discussion

Perhaps this widget fits your needs: http://perfectwidgets.com/Main being more specific this ones: http://perfectwidgets.com/Demo/Gallery#Gauges/0

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
      width: 1600, height: 480,
      redFrom: 0, redTo: 35,
      redColor: "rgba(198, 0, 0, 0.67)",
      yellowFrom: 36, yellowTo: 49,
      yellowColor: "rgba(219, 190, 0, 0.67)",
      greenFrom: 25, greenTo: 45,
      minorTicks: 5
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a gauge chart with 5 colours, each taking 20% of the scale. I solved the problem as follows:

- draw a gauge with 2 colors (result is a svg image)
- copy the `<path>` tags of the two colors
- draw a gauge with three colors (the maximum)
- add the two copied colours to the scale
  The result:

[image]

My code below

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gaugechart" title="" data-data="[[Element, Percentage],[Value 1,63]]"
        style="width: 225px; height: 225px;"></div>
    <div id="gaugechart" title="" data-data="[[Element, Percentage],[Value 2,41]]"
        style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {
            packages: ["gauge"]
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            let gauges;
            let gaugeArray = [];
            let options = {
                redFrom: 0, redTo: 20,
                yellowFrom: 40, yellowTo: 60,
                greenFrom: 80, greenTo: 100,
                yellowColor: "yellow",
                minorTicks: 10
            };
            let options1 = {
                redFrom: 20, redTo: 40,
                greenFrom: 60, greenTo: 80,
                redColor: "orange",
                greenColor: "lightgreen",
                minorTicks: 10
            };
            if (typeof this_editor != "undefined") {
                gauges = this_editor.contentDocument.querySelectorAll("div[id=gaugechart]");
            } else {
                gauges = document.querySelectorAll("div[id=gaugechart]");
            }
            if (gauges.length > 0) {
                gauges.forEach((userItem) => {
                    let dataset = userItem.dataset["data"]
                        .split("],[")
                        .map((e, i) => {
                            let arr = e.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").split(",");
                            if (i > 0) {
                                arr[1] = Number(arr[1]);
                            }
                            return arr;
                        });
                    let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataset);
                    let count = gaugeArray.push(chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(userItem)) - 1;
                    gaugeArray[count].draw(data, (options1));
                    let p = userItem.querySelectorAll("g path");
                    let x = document.createElement("path");
                    x.setAttribute("d", p[0].getAttribute("d"));
                    x.setAttribute("stroke", p[0].getAttribute("stroke"));
                    x.setAttribute("stroke-width", p[0].getAttribute("stroke-width"));
                    x.setAttribute("fill", "lightgreen");
                    let y = document.createElement("path");
                    y.setAttribute("d", p[1].getAttribute("d"));
                    y.setAttribute("stroke", p[1].getAttribute("stroke"));
                    y.setAttribute("stroke-width", p[1].getAttribute("stroke-width"));
                    y.setAttribute("fill", "orange");
                    gaugeArray[count].draw(data, (options));
                    userItem.querySelector("g path").after(x);
                    userItem.querySelector("g path").after(y);
                    userItem.innerHTML = userItem.innerHTML;
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```